# Force heartbeat change active node

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, heartbeat

Is there a way to force heartbeat change active node?
Or may be force to node to release resources so that one of other node take it.

Ubuntu 12.04
Heartbeat

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should have some scripts (probably in `/usr/share/heartbeat`) called

`hb_standby`
`hb_takeover`

You can run hb_standby on the active node to release resources.